# Can't find the webpart after deployment

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Whenever I deploy solution to my Sharepoint 2010,Visual Studio says "deployment was successful", but the webpart is still missing. Feature is in the "Site Features" and it is activated. But webpart is not in webparts collection (Site Setings->Web Parts)

Any idea why?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the Webpart to the feature.

In your solution explorer double-click on the feature and make sure your webpart is part of the items under "Items in the Feature"